# absolute links and ssl

Tags: ssl, cross-browser

I've found some conflicting information regarding SSL and links of external sources.  In one web source, the writer says that all external resources should be explicitly made as https. His solution would be to use "//" (an https connection of the url would lead to an https connection of the resource) as in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//css/styles.css" />
```

On another page, I saw that as long as the external resource is coming from your domain, it won't be an issue.  So for example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

or

(more explicitly)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://www.mycoolwebsite.com/css/styles.css" />
```

would both work.

I've tested my https connection in Firefox using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

and it worked fine, but it also seems that SSL may not work on all browsers, so I'm not convinced that my 1 browser check is indicative of a solution that will work wherever SSL works.

Which would be the best approach for my external css/javascript files that reside on my own domain?

Comment: What makes you think that 'SSL may not work on all browsers'?

Comment: Maybe I should say "certificates"?  I thought that I had read that some SSL certificates won't be recognized by all browsers.